# VHDL error: Ambiguous type in infix expression; reg_buff or data_buff

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl, modelsim

i get the following error in ModelSim when doing a type conversion

> Ambiguous type in infix expression; reg_buff or data_buff.
>
> Error: (vcom-1583) Illegal type converson from 'unknown' to
>   'ieee.NUMERIC_STD.UNSIGNED' (operand type is not known).

```
--declaration of types:                 
type packet_ipg_array is 
    array (1 downto 0) of integer;

type packet_buffer_array is 
    array (1 downto 0, packet_buffer_size-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

variable packet_ipg     : packet_ipg_array; 
variable packet_buffers : packet_buffer_array; 

--conversion:
packet_ipg(i) := 
    to_integer(unsigned(
          packet_buffers(i,packet_buffer_bytes_sent(i))(7 downto 0) 
        & packet_buffers(i,packet_buffer_bytes_sent(i)+1)(7 downto 0)  
        & packet_buffers(i,packet_buffer_bytes_sent(i)+2)(7 downto 0)  
        & packet_buffers(i,packet_buffer_bytes_sent(i)+3)(7 downto 0)
    ));
```

Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: It would be better if you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to help better, not just the error part of the code

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what's wrong, but would want to test my answer before committing. If you post an MCVE then I can test my answer.

Comment: The signals in question don't even seem to be in the code you posted, namely `reg_buff` and `data_buff`.

Comment: "infix expression" isn't a term of art found in IEEE Std 1076 where the closest analog is "binary operator" (-2008, 9.2.2 Logical operators) and is not applied to arithmetic operators (here "+" as shown in Matthew's edit). The expression `packet_buffer_bytes_sent(i)` is ambiguous here, and you're missing a context clause as well as declarations for packet_buffer_size, i, and packet_buffer_bytes_sent (which if it were of type packet_ipg_array the expression would be unambiguous).  Provide a [mcve]. Is packet_buffer_bytes_sent a function?

Comment: You could also note 4 eight element slices of standard logic vector values can when converted to unsign provide a value out of range for an unsigned value expressed as an integer (0 to 2**31 - 1, for portable declarations of type INTEGER in package STD.STANDARD as implemented by Modelsim currently).